# How to stop smoke simulation from rising?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I have a smoke simulation. How do I get it to not float up?

Comment: Posted this so I don't forget... because I undoubtedly will. And someone else might too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Set the density and temp diff to zero